# Merge subtree changes if different commit histories

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit, git-subtree, lerna

I'm trying to use [splitsh-lite](https://github.com/splitsh/lite) to expose packages from a monorepo as manyrepos.

But how can I merge a pull request made to a manyrepo back into the monorepo?

`splitsh-lite` is a git subtree replacement and creates all new commit ids while otherwise essentially keeping the same commit history. The idea is that the manyrepo stays readonly, PRs get merged into the monorepo, and from there are distributed back to the manyrepos again. Now, a simple subtree merge of a PR returns

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Is there a git trick to achieve this, given that we know there's a "last matching commit" before the PR commit(s)?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't—it's not designed to work in that direction.  You are supposed to make all pull requests directly to the original monorpeo, which of course also means that you must clone / fork the original monorepo and do your work there.

The `git subtree` code does allow you to work in both directions (within limits).  This other alternative you are exploring does not.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't this contradict what the author is saying about PRs specifically (https://youtu.be/4w3-f6Xhvu8?t=1106: "but then you need to move it") and the access control use-case in general (https://youtu.be/4w3-f6Xhvu8?t=904). In this sense, going both ways seems like a core benefit of splitsh(-lite)

Comment: I'm going based on the slides, not the youtube introduction; maybe they added more features since then. It's fundamentally a bit tricky to go both ways, but you're right that there's a "last matching commit", so it should be possible.